# Cannot found package sudo - 1.8.9p5-1ubuntu1.5+esm6 for armor arch

Tags: ubuntu, security, arm, embedded-linux, sudo

As for the title

Cannot find package sudo - 1.8.9p5-1ubuntu1.5+esm6 for armor arch

it appears as released here https://ubuntu.com/security/notices/USN-4705-2

but cannot find it anywhere

thanks in advance

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I mean using the apt command or browsing the repositories, it's simply missing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This package is part of the Ubuntu ESM (Extended Security Maintenance) which is available with Ubuntu advantage: https://ubuntu.com/advantage.

This is indicated in the package name: `sudo - 1.8.9p5-1ubuntu1.5+esm6`  (Note the **esm**)

If you are searching for personal use it states:

> Anyone can use UA-I Essential for free on up to 3 machines, or 50 if
> you are an official Ubuntu Community member

If you are looking for professional reasons you need an enterprise license which you can get from the Ubuntu advantage link above

Since I was looking for the same package as well... Our course of action in the company will be upgrading to a new LTS version of Ubuntu.

Comment: Thank you very much, I found exactly the same information but your answer is welcome.